# exclude my angular2 rc app files from systemjs-builder

Tags: angular, systemjs

I want to create a js file with my angular2 dependencies **BUT exclude** my app js files.

Because in every change i make in a ts file (for example my clientList.component.ts) i have to rebuild the bundle.

This is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('bundle:angular', function () {
var builder = new Builder('', './systemjs.config.js');
return builder
    .buildStatic('./wwwroot/ngApp/main.js', './wwwroot/js/libs/angular.bundle.js',
                        { minify: true, sourceMaps: true})
    .then(function (output) {
        console.log('Build complete');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Build error');
    });
});
```

And this is my systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    var map = {
        'app': './wwwroot/ngApp',
        'rxjs': './wwwroot/js/libs/rxjs',
        '@angular': './wwwroot/js/libs/@angular'
    };
    var packages = {
         'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
          'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };

    var packageNames = [
         '@angular/common',
         '@angular/compiler',
         '@angular/core',
         '@angular/http',
         '@angular/platform-browser',
         '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
         '@angular/router',
         '@angular/router-deprecated',
         '@angular/testing',
         '@angular/upgrade'
    ];
  packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
     packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
     map: map,
     packages: packages
  }

   if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }
   System.config(config);

 })(this);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will do,

```ts
gulp.task('bundle:angular', function () {
var builder = new Builder('', './systemjs.config.js');
return builder
    .buildStatic('./wwwroot/ngApp/main.js - @angular', './wwwroot/js/libs/angular.bundle.js',
                        { minify: true, sourceMaps: true})
    .then(function (output) {
        console.log('Build complete');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Build error');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a static bundle (i.e. one that can be loaded by `<script>` directly) of your app which includes all dependencies, thus angular. To separate your app from angular (or any other library) you would have to build the vendor bundle by creating a file that `require`'s all dependencies. The app bundle would have to be the difference between app and its dependencies and the vendor bundle.

https://github.com/systemjs/builder#example---common-bundles

However, if what you're after is turnaround time after changing source files, I would recommend looking at webpack. It has plugins to create delta bundles and with its webpack-dev-server it is very quick at rebuilding what has changed (about 2 seconds in my setup). I don't think you can get similar quick turnaround times using SystemJS.